# Spring Boot - Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, jpa-2.0

I have an entity class called `ItemType` with the following relation:

```
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true,targetEntity = BinaryObjectType.class, cascade = {
    javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL
})
@JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_IMAGE_ITEM_TYPE_HJID")
public List<BinaryObjectType> getProductImage() {
    if (productImage == null) {
        productImage = new ArrayList<BinaryObjectType>();
    }
    return this.productImage;
}
```

Then, `BinaryObjectType` has the following relation:

```
@Basic
@Column(name = "VALUE_")
@Lob
public byte[] getValue() {
    return value;
}
```

I've created a custom repository in a Spring Boot application just for testing as follows:

```
package eu.nimble.service.catalogue.config;
@Service
@Transactional(transactionManager = "barTransactionManager")
public class CustomRepo {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("barEntityManager")
    private EntityManager em;

    public ItemType getItem() {
        String query = "SELECT it FROM ItemType it WHERE it.hjid = 147";
        Query q = em.createQuery(query);
        List<ItemType> i = q.getResultList();
        return i.get(0);
    }
}
```

And finally, the DB config has been instantiated as follows:

```
@Bean(name = "barDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "persistence.orm.ubl.spring")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean(name = "barEntityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean barEntityManagerFactory(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier("barDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfBean = builder
                    .dataSource(dataSource)
                    .persistenceUnit("ubl-data-model")
                    .build();
    return emfBean;
}

@Primary
@Bean(name = "barEentityManagerFactory")
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(
        @Qualifier("barDataSource") DataSource dataSource, 
        @Qualifier("barEntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfBean) {
    return emfBean.getObject();
}

@Bean(name = "barTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager barTransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("barEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory barEntityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(barEntityManagerFactory);
}

@Bean(name = "barEntityManager")
public EntityManager entityManager(
        @Qualifier("barEentityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}
```

I can retrieve the `ItemType` instance from the DB but when I return the obtained instance via a REST service (see below), I get the following exception:

```
Could not write content: Unable to access lob stream (through reference chain: eu.nimble.service.model.ubl.commonaggregatecomponents.ItemType[\"productImage\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unable to access lob stream (through reference chain: eu.nimble.service.model.ubl.commonaggregatecomponents.ItemType[\"productImage\"])
```

The complete stack trace is as follows:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: Unable to access lob stream (through reference chain: eu.nimble.service.model.ubl.commonaggregatecomponents.ItemType["productImage"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unable to access lob stream (through reference chain: eu.nimble.service.model.ubl.commonaggregatecomponents.ItemType["productImage"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:274)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:232)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:130)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter.doFilter(TraceFilter.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unable to access lob stream (through reference chain: eu.nimble.service.model.ubl.commonaggregatecomponents.ItemType["productImage"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:379)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:339)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:343)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:698)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:292)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1419)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:940)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:267)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to access lob stream
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.wrap(PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.wrap(PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.java:26)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BlobTypeDescriptor$1.doExtract(BlobTypeDescriptor.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2738)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.loadFromResultSet(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.hydrateEntityState(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:688)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1991)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:570)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:261)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:102)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode.
    at org.postgresql.largeobject.LargeObjectManager.open(LargeObjectManager.java:265)
    at org.postgresql.largeobject.LargeObjectManager.open(LargeObjectManager.java:251)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.AbstractBlobClob.getLo(AbstractBlobClob.java:275)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.AbstractBlobClob.getBinaryStream(AbstractBlobClob.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.wrap(PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.java:115)
    ... 103 more
```

The REST service is a simple one as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/temp",
        produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity tempMethod() {
    ItemType c = repo.getItem();
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(c);
}
```

So, how can I return the data properly? I already tried to set the `hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans` to `true` and `hibernate.connection.autocommit` to `false` without success. I also tried to add `getCatalogueByUuid` to the REST service method (i.e `tempMethod`) as well as to the repository method i.e. `getItem`.

Thanks for your helps in advance.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of the error.

Comment: OK. Added the stacktrace. Thanks!